# How compiler overloades template function without argument list change?

Tags: c++, c++14

As you can see in the code below method `get` is templated.

```
struct A
{
    int i;
    char c;
};

class SL
{
    static void* m_a;


public:

    template <class T>
    static T* get()
    {
        return static_cast<T*>(m_a);
    }
};

void* SL::m_a = new A{12, 'C'};

int main()
{
    std::cout << SL::get<A>()->i;
    return 0;
}
```

What I do not understand is when I write `SL::get<B>()` how a compiler creates two methods with the same name, in the same namespace, with two different return types that both does not have parameters, i.e. does not have different argument list? How they overload each-other? Or it is wrong to understand temple function generation to have the same names and interpret their call via overload resolution?

Comment: in which universe is `get<A>` the same name as `get<B>`? I distinctly see a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Template *instantions* are really *different* functions which are not overloaded.
You may think of the template parameters `<B>` as a part of the function name.
So `SL::get<A>` and `SL::get<B>` are really different functions (though stemming from the same template).

Quoting from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template):

> Template argument deduction takes place after the function template name lookup (which may involve argument-dependent lookup) and before overload resolution.

As you see, overload resolution is a different process.

Comment: So template argument deduction is before overload resolution? I know that overloaded functions win template functions as they are more specialized. Then why template argument deduction comes before overload resolution?

Comment: Because without template argument deduction, you wouldn't have any *function* to select an overload from. Note that a function *template* is *not* a function. You first have to *instantiate* templates (by argument deduction), before you can proceed with *selecting* which function fits best (by overload resolution).

Answer (score 3):

This is compiler specific and you shouldn't worry about it too much. A general idea of how it's done though:

Say you call the templated method with 2 different types

```
SL::get<A>();
SL::get<B>();
```

The compiler generates 2 new methods for these calls:

```
static A* get_a()
{
  // etc..
}
```

and

```
static B* get_b()
{
  // etc..
}
```

This may differ from compiler to compiler but it shows how a compiler avoids name clashes. To the programmer, it's the same method being called twice, to a compiler it's just 2 different methods called by different pieces code.

Answer (score 2):

Templates are prone to [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) as anything else. When the exact `get` is generated, it's not really called `get` anymore, it will be called something like `get@YUQIE` or similar. You can check [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyx5b79y(v=vs.90).aspx) for an example. This is implementation-defined though, so different compilers will do it in a different way. For example, in the following code

```
template <class T>
T get()
{
    return T();
}

int main()
{
    get<int>();
    get<char>();
    return 0;
}
```

`get` was mangled by gcc as `_Z3getIiEPT_v` for `get<int>` and `_Z3getIcEPT_v` for `get<char>`.